# View conditional logic based on dropdown value

Tags: views

I have a `view` that is outputting fields from a `paragraph`. I want to be able to output different markup. There are two available values in the dropdown

```
1|Wrapping Link
2|Internal Link
```

and they should determine if the markup is wrapped by a link or if the same link is a contained within the markup as a stand-alone link.

In my custom version of `views-view-fields.html.twig` I want to have some logic in place that will check the value of the dropdown and display the correct markup. I have tried the following but this is invalid.

```
{%- if {{ fields.field_banner_type.content }} = "1" -%}
    // wrapping link
{%- else -%}
    // no wrapping link
{%- endif %}
```

Comment: I think no need fo {{ in if statement did you try with `{% if fields.field_banner_type.content == 1 %}
    // wrapping link
{% else %}
    // no wrapping link
{% endif %}`

Comment: You've solved my syntax errors but it outputs `// wrapping lnk` irrespective of the dropdown value selected. The field is outputting the value as opposed to the key so I'm guessing I need to get access to this

Comment: if the output is `// wrapping lnk` thats  because the if condition verified, and the comment in twig should be like `{#wrapping lnk #}` not `// wrapping lnk `

Comment: Ah, so the solution was the following `{% if fields.field_banner_type.content == 'Wrapping Link' %}`. Even if I set the formatter of the view for this filed to `key` I still had to set it as a string in the twig file - e.g. `{% if fields.field_banner_type.content == '1' %}`. All good now. Thanks, @berramou

Comment: You are welcome, i'm glad that help.

Comment: I will post it as answer if someone  needs it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to `{{ fields.field_banner_type.content }}` inside if statement use `fields.field_banner_type.content` like the following:

```
{% if fields.field_banner_type.content == "1" %}
  {# wrapping link #}
{% else %}
  {# no wrapping link #}
{% endif %}
```

For more info See [Twig if Documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html)